# Jboss7.1 Change Server Banner response header

Tags: httpresponse, jboss7.x

For some security reasons in out project the normal server  banner header

Server : Apache-Coyote/1.1

Needs to be changed, I have tried adding  following in the standalone.xml system properties

```
<property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.SERVER" value="secureserver"/>
```

But this doesn't seems to work, is there any other setting or property change to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this page](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/sysprops.html) , the way you are trying to do it is correct.

Please check if you have followed the below line - which is specified in the document

> Or edit the standalone.xml and add afiter the extensions: